# I'm trying to move my application from MS SQL Server to MySQL, and im facing issues issues with MySQL "Limit" in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to move my application from MS SQL Server to MySQL, and I'm facing an issues with MySQL's `LIMIT` clause in a subquery.

SQL Server code:

```
select F.call_Id, F.cell_Phone_Number, F.cal_DATE
From TD_Call_Log AS F
Where F.call_Id IN ( Select Top 5 S.call_Id
                      From TD_Call_Log AS S
                      where S.cell_Phone_Number = F.cell_Phone_Number)

 Order by cell_Phone_Number
```

MySQL code that I have tried:

```
select F.call_Id, F.cell_Phone_Number, F.cal_DATE
From TD_Call_Log F
Where F.call_Id IN (Select S.call_Id
                      From TD_Call_Log S
                      where S.cell_Phone_Number = F.cell_Phone_Number Limit 5)

 Order by cell_Phone_Number
```

and I have also tried:

```
select F.call_Id, F.cell_Phone_Number, F.cal_DATE
From TD_Call_Log F INNER JOIN (Select S.call_Id
                      From TD_Call_Log S 
 where S.cell_Phone_Number = F.cell_Phone_Number Limit 5) as t
                      ON F.call_Id = t.call_Id

 Order by cell_Phone_Number
```

Comment: Check if its working after specifying table alias name at
'Order by F.cell_Phone_Number'

Comment: Good luck with mysql and subqueries!

Comment: If you're getting any error please post it.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'F.cell_Phone_Number' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your subquery within In clause with an Inner join.

```
select F.call_Id, F.cell_Phone_Number, F.cal_DATE
From TD_Call_Log AS F 
INNER JOIN 
(
Select S.call_Id, S.cell_Phone_Number
From TD_Call_Log S
Limit 5
)
sub
where sub.cell_Phone_Number = F.cell_Phone_Number and F.call_Id = sub.call_Id
Order by cell_Phone_Number
```

Comment: it limits  the total result to 5, as oppose to 5 of each phone number